# Where I can get ROUTE target for iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

I need the "new" ROUTE patch on the netfilter. This one: http://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.5

So, in xtables-addons no ROUTE. I google the ROUTE.patch, but nothing...

Maybe this: http://www.netfilter.org/projects/patch-o-matic/pom-external.html#pom-external-ROUTE But there i can't find patch file.

I'm using Archlinux with kernel 3.1. So, I need help.

Answer (score 5):

ROUTE is a deprecated target and no longer available; to influence packet routing, use MARK or CONNMARK and use iproute2 to perform routing based on applied marks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what exactly you want to achieve. But most probably your problem can be solved using combination of iproute2 utilities and iptables.

In this you create additional routing tables. These are added in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
And then you set up the routing rules to choose what routing table to route with.
OR
You can mark specific packet using iptables using -j MARK –set-mark 1 and then again using iproute2 utilities you can use a particular routing table ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1.

"advanced routing" might be the keywords.

The link you mentioned says

> Whenever possible, you should use the MARK target together with
>   iproute2 instead of this ROUTE target. However, this target is useful
>   to force the use of an interface or a next hop and to change the
>   incoming interface of a packet. People also use it for easiness and to
>   simplify their rules (one rule to route a packet is easier that one
>   MARK rule + one iproute2 rule).

you may look at

http://lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.RPDB.MULTIPLE-LINKS

http://www.adamsinfo.com/netfilter-iptables-split-access-with-multiple-isps/#.TsphIWMgfpA

Comment: If iproute2 is available (for some systems it is not) it surely should be the preferred way of doing things.